# Java logging performance

Tags: java, logging, wildfly

I am using wildfly21 set to log **level=INFO**. In the deployed code there are a lot of logger.debug statements.

e.g

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass.getName());
logger.debug("Some debug message");
```

The debug statements are correctly not being logged to file as the logging level is set to INFO.

My question is around the performance cost of **logger.debug**.

Is there any performance cost in keeping the debug statements in code. Or is the real cost in the File I/O and as such there is no harm in leaving the debug statements for troubleshooting purposes when needed.

Comment: `Or is the real cost in the File I/O` I'm no expert but I believe the real cost is in the IO, so you should be fine.  One thing to be aware of is statements like this `logger.debug( "Concat " + i +  " a " + param + " string " + x );` *DO* incur the cost of building a string.  You should substitute a version that doesn't do the string cocatenation unless the statement is actually logged: `logger.debug( "Concat {0} a {1} string {2}", i, param, x );`

Comment: Thanks I had totally overlooked the cost string concat.

Comment: Depending on the logging framework you use, you might also be able to leverage lambdas to create your logging messages. They will only be invoked if the logger is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

When your logging call is low cost such as with string literal (or the String format variant suggested by @markspace) you can use `logger.debug` as you have above:

```
logger.debug("Some debug message");
```

However if the statement has a side effect cost such as:

```
logger.debug("Value of X="+x+" extra bits "+someSideEffect(y));
```

... then always prefix with a check on logging level before use. Most Logger APIs support `isXYZEnabled` or `logger.isEnabled(Level.XYZ)` to determine whether the log message is used:

```
if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
    logger.debug("Value of X="+x+" extra bits "+someSideEffect(y));
```

This avoids any possible impact from the unnecessary String creation and other computations performed by the unused logging levels, and there is no need to comment out debug statements when info level logging is used.

Comment: I always wanted to know , why would someone have a method call in a log statement ? Wouldnt you be using that method call someSideEffect(y) somewhere in code , so it makes sense to keep it in variable ?

Comment: @voucher_wolves Some times this is necessary to format data appropriately for logging (e.g. convert to hex or base64).